# Python "Invalid rgb arg "None""

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a code that creates and saves a plot, using matplotlib and python. The code runs flawlessly at the laptop of my supervisor, who has matplotlib 1.1.1. However, despite the fact that I have a newer version of matplotlib(1.3.1) I get the following error when executing this command:

```
plt.savefig("outputs/" + run_uuid +".pdf", facecolor='white', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

I get the following Traceback on that command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vis.py", line 1116, in <module>
    plt.savefig("outputs/" + run_uuid +".pdf", facecolor='white', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2167, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1952, in print_pdf
    return pdf.print_pdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2352, in print_pdf
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/axisartist/axislines.py", line 774, in draw
    super(Axes, self).draw(renderer, inframe)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/lines.py", line 530, in draw
    gc.set_foreground(ln_color_rgba)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 921, in set_foreground
    self._rgb = colors.colorConverter.to_rgba(fg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/colors.py", line 365, in to_rgba
    'to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "%s"\n%s' % (str(arg), exc))
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "None"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "None"
cannot convert argument to rgb sequence
```

I couldn't find anything useful in the net for this error. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

I also tried to rewrite this

```
plt.savefig("outputs/" + run_uuid +".pdf", facecolor='white', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.0)
```

to this:

```
plt.savefig("outputs/" + run_uuid +".pdf")
```

but without any progress

Comment: The problem is in code that you have not shown use.  mpl is lazy and does not render anything until you tell it to.  Unfortunately this also means that some parameters don't get validated until render time.

Answer (score 1):

I think reason is facecolor doesn't have value of 'white'.

From [the following link](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps), no 'white' exists in facecolor setting.

what if simply use plt.savefig("your path")? I think default background color should be white.

Comment: Thanks a lot linpingta for your answer. However, this does not work for me... It still produces the same error in the exact same line. Any other idea?

Comment: so plt.savefig("your path") also returns that problem? from callstack I guess it's only related with facecolor a it called colors.py and wrong in 'to_rgba' function~

Comment: No, of course there is white color :) You can see that from here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/colors.py. Yes, plt.savefig("your path")  also produces that problem. colors.py mentions that it does not have the color "None".